# Unable to add UITextViewCell's accessoryType

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8.1

I need to get addressability to the UITableView cell so I can set the checkmark if the user has previously selected that row. Initially, the user checks the tableViewCell, I move that to a textField and store it in Core Data. Now if the user wants to change something in the UITableView, I want to be able to show what is already checked or unchecked.

So, I have a UITableView that I present in a UIPopover (outside of *-cellForRowAtIndexPath*); if a particular cell has a text value equal to an element in a NSArray, I want to set the cell's accessoryType to checked.  This is my **UPDATED** code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

//  get the timeFormat
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableDictionary *preferencesDict = [[userDefaults dictionaryForKey:@"preferencesDictionary"] mutableCopy];
int iTimeFormat = [[preferencesDict objectForKey:@"timeFormat"] intValue];  //  set timeFormat

if(tableView.tag == kServicesTableView) {  //  services array

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"servicesCell";  //  servicesCell is just an identifier; not used that I can tell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault) reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    SingletonServicesArray *sharedServicesArray = [SingletonServicesArray sharedServicesArray];  //  initialize

    [cell.textLabel setText:[sharedServicesArray.globalServicesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    if( ![soServices hasText] )  {  //  no text in text box
        for (int i = 0; i < sharedServicesArray.globalServicesArray.count; i++) {
            NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];

            //  if row has been checked, remove the check
            UITableViewCell *cell = [servicesTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
            if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                 break;
            }
        }
    }
    else  {  //  not empty
        for (int i = 0; i < sharedServicesArray.globalServicesArray.count; i++) {
            NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
            UITableViewCell *cell = [servicesTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];

            //  if row is in soServices textfield, add a checkmark
            if ([soServices.text containsString: sharedServicesArray.globalServicesArray[i]])  {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return cell;

}
```

It's not working; I know for sure at least two of the services are in the array, so I should have two cells with checkmarks; I'm getting zilch!.  How do I get this to work correctly?

Comment: Where (in terms of controller's lifecycle) is that block of code executed? Also, wouldn't make more sense to set the cell's accessory type inside `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? Also, a breakpoint would help in order to inspect `cell` (remember in ObjC sending a message to `nil` is valid)

Comment: Did you reload the table view after updating the cell (`[self.tableview reloadData]`)? As Alladinian mentioned, this type of check would be better in your `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to ensure that the cell's properties are being set correctly and not overwritten when cells are reused.

Comment: I'm assuming you're saying that you can't because you don't have access to that array in the class that declares `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  If that's the case, I'd recommend the simple solution of giving that class access to the array to do this check in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (where you can add an else condition to remove the checkmark so it is not there in the case of cell reuse). Then in your popover, you can reload the tableview.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you're trying to accomplish here. If you are presenting a UITableView in the popover, what class is populating this tableview? If you have a class populating the tableview, you should have a `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method somewhere. It seems like you should create a subclass of UITableViewCell, add properties to the cell (ie. the textfield you are trying to read), access those properties in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to determine if that cell should have a checkmark or not.

Comment: Also, in your code above, you are looping through your data source (sharedServicesArray.globalServicesArray) and attempting to get a cell with  `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`... this cannot be trusted, as your `servicesTableView` may not be displaying that cell at that point in time. This is why you depend on `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to modify your cells, because it runs every time the cell is created. You should not be getting UITableViewCells with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`, not `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`.

Comment: Tim: that's *exactly* what I'm trying to do... this **-cellForRowAtIndexPath** is in the same class (Appointments.m) that I'm trying to set the attributes in, only from different method.  So now, I have moved the checking code to **-cellForRowAtIndexPath**.  The code finds the data being compared and sets the attribute in **-cellForRowAtIndexPath**, but it doesn't appear when I display the tableView.  (hope that makes sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it correctly, this cellForRowAtIndexPath is updating the cells of a DIFFERENT tableView. It would be more logical to add the above code to the cellForRowAtIndexPath of the tableView that needs updating.

In case you are trying to update the cells of that tableView, then the following code would not work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sharedServicesArray.globalServicesArray.count; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [servicesTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];

        //  if row is in soServices textfield, add a checkmark
        if ([soServices.text containsString: sharedServicesArray.globalServicesArray[i]])  {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Instead, you would write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sharedServicesArray.globalServicesArray.count; i++) {
    //  if row is in soServices textfield, add a checkmark
    if ([soServices.text containsString: sharedServicesArray.globalServicesArray[i]])  {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much... I'll fix it... SD